# CakePHP 2 .10.0 "OR" condition is not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using Cakephp 2.10.0. While working with find condition, I am facing a strange issues LIKE "OR" condition convert automatically to "AND" e.g

I am making find condition like:

```
$this->{$this->leadCall}->find('list', array('conditions'=>array($this->leadCall.'.future_call !=' => date('m/d/Y'), 'or' => array($this->leadCall.'.future_call !=' => '')),'fields' => array('lead_id')));
```

It results

```
SELECT `LeadCall`.`id`, `LeadCall`.`lead_id` FROM `zindagihomes`.`lead_calls` AS `LeadCall` WHERE `LeadCall`.`future_call` != '11/19/2017' AND `LeadCall`.`future_call` != ''
```

And I want query something like this

```
SELECT `LeadCall`.`id`, `LeadCall`.`lead_id` FROM `zindagihomes`.`lead_calls` AS `LeadCall` WHERE `LeadCall`.`future_call` != '11/19/2017' OR `LeadCall`.`future_call` != ''
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my mistake. It was due wrong array formation.

```
<pre>
$conditions = array(
 'OR' => array(
    $this->leadCall.'.future_call !=' => date('m/d/Y'),
    $this->leadCall.'.future_call !=' => ''        
  )
);
$futureCall = $this->{$this->leadCall}->find('list', array('conditions'=>$conditions,'fields' => array('lead_id')));
</pre>
```

it is working fine as expected.

Comment: This won't create an `OR` condition, but an `AND` one. An `OR` condition wouldn't make much sense anyways, as it would match any value that isn't an empty string.

Comment: @ndm You are right. It will not create "OR" condition. Actually, I miss OR block while typing here.

Now it is updated.

Comment: This won't work. The `OR` array has two identical keys which will overwrite themselves. A workaround is to wrap each condition inside it's own array.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is still an issue in the code you shared because

```
    $this->leadCall.'.future_call !=' => date('m/d/Y'),
```

and

```
    $this->leadCall.'.future_call !=' => ''
```

are the same key so you replace it juste after setting it. I think it would be better to separate them in an other array

```
<pre>
$conditions = array(
 'OR' => array(
    array($this->leadCall.'.future_call !=' => date('m/d/Y')),
    array($this->leadCall.'.future_call !=' => '')        
  )
);
$futureCall = $this->{$this->leadCall}->find('list', array('conditions'=>$conditions,'fields' => array('lead_id')));
</pre>
```